# Mutual Information: Are these two equations equal?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm working with Multivariate Mutual Information (MMI), specifically with three variables $(X,Y,Z)$, applied to RNA sequences. The MMI equation that **I use** for three variables is based on entropy expression only:

$$MI(X,Y,Z)=H(X)+H(Y)+H(Z)-[H(X,Y)+H(Y,Z)+H(X,Z)]+H(X,Y,Z)$$

and entropy (in this equation) is defined as:

$$H(X_1, \ldots,X_n)=-\sum_{X_1} \cdots \sum_{X_n}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\log_2[f(x_1,\ldots,f_n)]$$

Recently, I found a paper where MMI for three variables is defined as:

$$MI(X,Y,Z)=MI(X,Y)+MI(X,Z)+MI(Y,Z)-[H(X)+H(Y)+H(Z)]+H(X,Y,Z)$$

Where MI is:

$$MI=\sum_{x,y}f(X,Y)\log_2[\frac{f(X,Y)}{f(X)f(Y)}]$$

and entropy in this equation is calculated similarly to the above one, except that there is not a negative symbol. I mean:

$$H(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = \sum_{X_1} \cdots \sum_{X_n} f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \log_2 [f(x_1, \ldots,f_n)]$$

However, when I compute both $MI(X,Y,Z)$ with the same parameters $(X,Y,Z)$ I got different values. Therefore, looks like both $MI(X,Y,Z)$ equation are not the same. Can someone, please, check if those two equation are equal or different. May be I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is some confusion in your first equation: It is not clear where the $[$ ends, since you close it twice. If the last term is positive, then the two equations are the same by recognizing that $MI(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)$.

Comment: "entropy in this equation is calculated similarly to the above one, except that there is not a negative symbol" Are you sure about that? That looks weird to me.